# Assign values twice

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on an old Macro file for Word, which I am maintaining since the original developer stopped working on it. The VBA script contains a calculation script which uses values from editfields (from a form) to make a final sum from the inserted hours, and after that it will drop it into a table inside a Word document like this:

```
Total hours 8 + 0,5 uur administration = 8,5 hours
```

However when the user removes the value from the form edit field and presses calculation again, the value is still inside the memory without overwriting it. But: There is a workaround, if I change the form values to 0.00 first and then remove the line, the formula gets changed.

Now I want to automate this process, and it partially worked:

```
If txtInspectieUren4 = "" Then txtInspectieUren4 = "0.00" //works!
```

But I don't want the "0.00" to be visible in my Word document, so I added this:

```
If txtInspectieUren4 = "" Then txtInspectieUren4 = "0.00" //works!
If txtInspectieUren4 = "0.00" Then txtInspectieUren4 = "" //Can I get the "" back after assigning "0.00"?
```

Answer (score 0):

So you added "this"... and then what?

A lot depends on how these form fields' properties are set, which you don't say. If txtInspectieUren4 is set as numerical then it can't contain an empty string and calculate correctly - it sounds as if that's the issue.

I'd try creating a bookmark in the document using a SET field. Have the code write the correct value (number or 0) to the bookmark and use this bookmark in the calculation rather than the form field that may or may not display a number.

a SET field looks like: { SET bookmarkName bookmarkValue }

Code to change it: `ActiveDocument.Fields([index]).Code.Text = "SET bookmarkName BookmarkValue"`

When formfields are used to do calculations and refer to other form fields they actually refer to the Bookmark names of the form fields and they can refer to any bookmarks in the document - not only form fields.